# Is there a way to set bounds on a variable in Java?

Tags: java, bounds

For instance can I have a variable

```
int x;
```

and tell the compiler x can never be greater than 20 or less than -20 without having to write a method to check the value every iteration through the loop? (I should mention here this is for a vector-based game's velocity variable.

Comment: Where do you need iterations in the situation you're trying to depict in the question?

Comment: you need to roll your own BoundedInt class.

Comment: Bounded< T extends Number >: poor performance guaranteed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only set the variables via a setter method. Inside of this method, throw an exception if it attempts to set the value out of range. Note that this won't work on the compiler side of things but rather at runtime which is where I believe this sort of check is necessary.

Comment: The usual pattern is to throw `IllegalArgumentException` from the setter when an out of range values is passed in.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'm accepting this answer since it was first and the others just confirmed what you said.

Answer (score 5):

no, you have to manually check it in your program

Answer (score 1):

```
assert  -20 < x && x < 20 : "Out of range!";
```

Executed with -ea argument, java will check the condition, without -ea the performance are at their best.

In case of assertion will not be verified [java.lang.AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) will be thrown